# Recommendation for new public display

Tags: embedded-systems, displays

We use a "Samsung SyncMaster 320MXn-3" as a public display in our entrance hall. 
The Windows XP Embedded is outdated and we are looking for an alterntive.

The only usage is: Some employees connect via teamviewer to the display and change a presentation powerpoint file which is started via Windows "autostart" in fullscreen. The display will shutdown in the evening and automatically boots every weekday.

The new display should satisfy the following specs:

- Display larger than 32" with VESA mount
- LAN Port
- up to date operating system
- Automatically start (best via bios setting) and shutdown (script)
- Possibility to (auto)start a presentation (or image file) in full screen. Preferable Microsoft Publisher 2010 or newer.
- Easy possibility to transfer the updated file from client to display for our users.

Do you have any recommendations?

Perhaps you have a completly different idea. Please let me know!

Comment: Do you have a budget?

Comment: Explain the pain point for XP embedded; where is it not serving your needs, specifically?